# Are the assumptions of linear regression fulfilled? (Dummy variables only)

Tags: regression, linear, assumptions

the dependent variable of my linear regression are stock returns of different companies. I have determined these stock returns with an event study and would now like to test the influence of different variables with a regression. Since all my explanatory variables are dummy variables, the question arises whether the assumptions of linear regression are fulfilled. In my opinion, they are fulfilled, but I would be very happy to receive help in this respect. Based on the image below, is there anything i have to worry about with respect to the assumptions of the linear regression?[image: Testing assumptions of linear regression]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The assumptions that are tested in these diagrams appear to be fine. You still have the assumption of randomness (you got a random sample of your population) and independent errors to deal with.